# Repeated initial sequence of random generator

Tags: c++

I need to gen pseudo-random numbers in the 0 : 23 range. I'm trying this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>


std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,23);

unsigned int random;

random = distribution(generator);
```

My problem is: Everytime I run my program, the first three random numbers is 0 , 3 , 18.

How can I solve this, and why this happens ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random values remain the same in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435685/random-values-remain-the-same-in-c)

Comment: A good start when asking for help would be to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. If you haven't done it yet, then please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You need to *seed* your generator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do these 4 different random number generator functions produce the same series of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48732245/why-do-these-4-different-random-number-generator-functions-produce-the-same-seri)

Answer (score 2):

Remember the P stands for "pseudo"!

A PRNG takes a seed to start generation of a pseudo random number sequence from. Since you don't provide it yourself, `std::default_random_engine` uses the same seed when default constructed. So you get the same sequence every time.

One possible and easy way to seed it, is to employ a `std::random_device` as a source for a little entropy:

```
std::random_device r;
std::default_random_engine generator(r());
```

If possible, `r` will produce a non-deterministic number. Otherwise, it too will be PRNG, so you aren't worse off. It's not the *best* scheme, but it should get you started.